# How to change database prefix when required.

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I've determined in my `database.php`:

```
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'm_';
```

Let say, if I want to use another prefix for example the table prefix started with `c_` instead of default database prefix `m_`, how I can do that?

My current code was:

```
$data['username'] = 'test_username';
$this->db->insert('c_my_table`, $data);
```

Any solution?